# python.sql in Zeppelin error: NameError: name 'pysqldf' is not defined

Tags: python, pandas, apache-zeppelin

New to Apache Zeppelin (Version 0.9.0-preview1). IT installed it, and been creating a new notebook. Trying to use python.sql and getting error: *NameError: name 'pysqldf' is not defined*.

Notebook paragraph 1:

```
%python
# download IMDB files, store in pandas dataframes
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dfTitles = pd.read_csv('https://datasets.imdbws.com/title.basics.tsv.gz', sep='\t', header=0, compression='gzip', index_col='tconst', usecols=['tconst', 'titleType', 'primaryTitle', 'originalTitle', 'startYear', 'endYear', 'runtimeMinutes', 'genres'], dtype='str')

# clean up and transform data
dfTitles.replace(to_replace={'startYear': r'\N', 'endYear': r'\N', 'runtimeMinutes': r'\N', 'genres': r'\N'}, value={'startYear': '0', 'endYear': '0', 'runtimeMinutes': '0', 'genres': ''}, inplace=True)
dfTitles = dfTitles.astype({'startYear': 'int32', 'endYear': 'int32'})
```

Notebook paragraph 2:

```
%python.sql
SELECT COUNT(primaryTitle), startYear FROM dfTitles WHERE startYear > ${minYear=1980} AND startYear <= 2020 GROUP BY startYear ORDER BY startYear
```

Paragraph 1 runs fine. Error after running paragraph 2:

> Fail to execute line 1: **zeppelin**.show(pysqldf('SELECT
> COUNT(primaryTitle), startYear FROM dfTitles WHERE startYear > 1980
> AND startYear <= 2020 GROUP BY startYear ORDER BY startYear'))
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/tmp/1603915922558-0/zeppelin_python.py", line 158, in 
> exec(code, _zcUserQueryNameSpace)   File "", line 1, in  NameError: name 'pysqldf' is not defined

I did read the [SQL over Pandas DataFrames](http://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.9.0-preview1/interpreter/python.html#sql-over-pandas-dataframes) documentation and it said the prerequisites were to run:

```
pip install pandas
pip install -U pandasql
```

But I couldn't run these in the notebook. If I need to run them, where do I run them from?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue by having IT reboot the Zeppelin server.

The server might have run out of memory, since I created a bunch of dataframes, etc. without cleaning up the memory.

I didn't have to run the "pip install" commands.

Got this resulting chart:
[image]